# How to change the button backgrounds inside JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton, joptionpane

I was wondering if anybody knew if it was possible to change the background color on the buttons inside a `JOptionPane`.  I know how to change the entire `JOptionPane` background using a `UIManager`, but know what I want is to set the individual okButton, cancelButton, and so on within the `JOptionPane` to separate individual colors.  If I can do this, how would I do this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Blender: I'm pretty sure the question is about Java Swing rather than html/css.

Comment: why? Generally, it's not the best idea to change the defaults, consistent visuals are there for a reason, changing them might confuse your users

Comment: You don't need to use UIManager because you can determine your own JButton.

Answer (score 7):

There is no direct way to do this.

But if you really want to give it a try, then you will need to read the JOptionPane API which gives code that shows you how to manually create and display a JOptionPane without using the showXXX methods.

Using this approach you now have access to the actuall JDialog. Then you can use Darryl's [SwingUtils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) to access the individual buttons and then set the background.

The code would be something like:

```
JButton ok = SwingUtils.getDescendantOfType(JButton.class, dialog, "Text", "Ok");
ok.setBackground(...);
```

Comment: +1. Really happy to hear that. I was looking for it from a lot of time. Do you know anything about the license under which SwingUtils are released?

Comment: @Heisenbug, The "About" page says you are free to use the code as you wish.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest would be to just create your own JDialog and set the button characteristics to your heart's content.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your own buttons with yours characteristics in `showOptionDialog`. I guess it is not the best solution, but it simply works.

```
JButton button = new JButton("OK");
button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
       JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
   }
});
JButton[] buttons = { button };
OptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Test Message", "Dialog", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon(), buttons, buttons[0]);
```

### [image]

Answer (score 2):

Add the the line of code below before your JOptionPane

```
UIManager.put("Button.background", Color.white);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Project, Please");
```