# temporarily disable ok button on a JDialog, accordingly to a JTextField validation

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jdialog, inputverifier

I have a JDialog created [in a fashion like this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/DialogDemoProject/src/components/CustomDialog.java), accordingly to Oracle's [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

using the JOptionPane constructor:

```
optionPane = new JOptionPane(array,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                null,
                options,
                options[0]);
```

I have no reference to the "yes" and "no" buttons, because they are created by the JOptionPane constructor.

Now, in my dialog I have a JFormattedText field with a InputValidator created by me that continuosly validate text field's input:

```
public class ValidatedDoubleField extends InputVerifier implements DocumentListener {

    private JTextField field;
    private Border defaultBorder;
    public ValidatedDoubleField(JFormattedTextField f){
        this.field = f;
        this.defaultBorder = f.getBorder();
        f.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        //System.out.println("verify");
        if (input instanceof JTextField){
            JTextField f = (JTextField)input;

            try{
                Double value = Double.parseDouble(f.getText().replace(',', '.'));
                return true;
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                return false;
            }
        }else if (input instanceof JFormattedTextField){
            JFormattedTextField f = (JFormattedTextField)input;

            try{
                Double value = Double.parseDouble(f.getText().replace(',', '.'));
                return true;
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input){

        boolean inputOK = verify(input);
        if (inputOK) {
            if (input instanceof JTextField){

                JTextField f = (JTextField)input;
                f.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                return true;
            }else if (input instanceof JFormattedTextField){

                JFormattedTextField f = (JFormattedTextField)input;

                f.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                return true;
            }else
                return false;
        } else {
            if (input instanceof JTextField){

                JTextField f = (JTextField)input;

                f.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                return false;
            }else if (input instanceof JFormattedTextField){

                JFormattedTextField f = (JFormattedTextField)input;

                f.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                return false;
            }else 
                return false;
        }
        //return true;

    }
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        this.field.getInputVerifier().shouldYieldFocus(field);
    }
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        this.field.getInputVerifier().shouldYieldFocus(field);
    }
    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.field.getInputVerifier().shouldYieldFocus(field);
    }

}
```

I posted the InputVerifier code even if it's not so relevant for the question.

Now what I would like to do is temporarily disable the "ok" button until the field will be validated, but I haven't a reference to it.

How can I do that?

I'm looking for something like:

```
JButton b = optionPane.getOkButton();
if (myFieldNotValidate)
     b.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Pointer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877994/how-to-change-the-button-backgrounds-inside-joptionpane)

Comment: @ring bearer: thanks. I solved with camickr solution. That's great!

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this to locate buttons at JOptionPane Dialog.

```
public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Test",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        null);

        List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

        loadButtons(optionPane, buttons);

    }

    public static void loadButtons(JComponent  comp, List<JButton> buttons) {
        if (comp == null) {
            return;     
        }

        for (Component c : comp.getComponents()) {
            if (c instanceof JButton) {
                buttons.add((JButton) c);

            } else if (c instanceof JComponent) {
                loadButtons((JComponent) c, buttons);
            }
        }
    }

}
```